# Click-to-call button not working on mobiles

Tags: html, iphone, mobile

I've created a click-to-call button for use on mobile devices, but I cannot get it to work. It's just a standard button:

```
<a href="tel:+01845527445" title="Click to call 01845 527 445">
  <span>01845 527 445</span>
</a>
```

The <span> wrapped around the number hides the text number itself, and instead shows a graphic button, which, when pressed, should trigger a call. The graphic button is used at the request of the client.

Can anyone suggest why this isn't working?

Thanks,

Kelly

Comment: works on iPhone's mail app.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement isn't possible to be implemented at the moment.

- When you use a webview to make a call, you can't remove the alert as it is the UIWebView behaviour.
- If you want, you can use the telprompt:// URL scheme. However, there is a risk that this URL scheme might get removed in future.

  ```
   NSString *phoneNumber = @"1-545-554-1234";
   NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];
   NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
  ```